# how to get documents that have an attribute containing a specific string in firestore?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a collection /ITEMS that have 1M documents. Each document have NAME attribute formatted string. I want to search and get all items that have NAME attribute containing specific string such as 'byces'.
My code as below:

```
var searchStr = 'byces';    
searchItem(searchStr: string) {
        firebase.firestore().collection('ITEMS')
        .onSnapshot((qSnap)=>{
          let RESULT = [];
          qSnap.docs.forEach(doc=>{
            let ITEM = doc.data();
            let index = ITEM.NAME.toLocaleLowerCase().indexOf(searchStr.toLocaleLowerCase());
            if(index>=0){
              RESULT.push(ITEM);
            }
          })
        })
      }
```

each time searchItem() function called, firebase will charge my project 1 million reads. It is too costly.

Is there any suggestion to save cost? Any recommendation on this case? Thanks for your reading.

Comment: It's hard to recommend a solution when we don't know what exactly your data looks like, and how you need to query it.  Firestore doesn't have substring queries, so you'll have to find a way to populate data in your documents that allows for exact matches on the substrings you're looking for.

Comment: As Doug say, substrings are not possible.  You can search at the beginning of the string.  However, if you want a full text search, you should check [Cloud Firestore > Full Text Search](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/search)